# Jackson and Hibernate Lazy loaded entities

Tags: json, hibernate, lazy-loading, jackson

I would like to know how to control the jackson deserialization of a lazy loaded entity.
For example, my setup contains two entities

```
Country 1------many State and 
State many----1 Country
```

Now when I load the country and serialize into JSON, it goes into and infinite recursion between fetching a country's states and the state's country and so on and then errors out.

I would like to stop at fetching at one level only. Say for country stop just at state(or just its id attribute) and need not fetch its country.
How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097865/jackson-confused-with-bidirectional-one-to-many-relationship