# JAX-RS JSON serialization loop with JPA entities

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I am developing a typical Java EE 7 application on Glassfish 4.0, using Netbeans 7.4. I have a set of JPA entities with all kinds of relationships. As it is probably a well-known issue, I face a problem (most likely caused by a serialization loop) when I try to expose an entity with a bidirectional relationship with another one using a JAX-RS service.

I have searched a lot for the solution. Apparently, the most clean way of solving this is to use Jackson providers instead of Jersey built-in ones. However, it has not been a success for me. I may be doing something wrong in the middle, and any hint would be much appreciated.

First Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "owner",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<Playlist> playlists;

    ...

}
```

Second Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Playlist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    ...

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    ...

}
```

JAX-RS Service:

```
@Path("/user")
@Stateless
public class UserResource {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{username}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("username") String username) {
        return Response.ok(userService.getUser(username)).build();
    }

}
```

I have downloaded and included latest Jackson binary (jackson-core-2.3.1.jar) in my classpath and I can actually see something related to jackson in Glassfish server log when I deploy my application. If the returned user entity does not have any associated playlists, everything is fine. However, with one or more playlists for the specified user, a HTTP 500 error is returned and nothing shows up in Glassfish server log.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

After lots of back and forth. I am still unable to make jackson work. I moved to Wildfly (Jboss 8), and I cannot make it use the provided version of jackson instead of the built-in one. No matter which version of jackson is added in the classpath (with or without Maven), the error always indicates org.codehaus.jackson.*.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `Playlist` entity class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"owner"})
public class Playlist {
```

Your Jackson is running to recurency when he tries to serialize User which have Playlist which have User and so on...

Comment: It doesn't work. If there is a suspicion that jackson is not active or is not able to read this annotation, I don't know actually how to make sure. Anyway, it would not be a good solution simply because I may want to expose a playlist through a RESTful service, and it that case, I certainly want the owner to be serialized too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630096/cyclic-references-in-a-bidirectional-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340485/how-to-solve-circular-reference-in-json-serializer-caused-by-hibernate-bidirecti

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097865/jackson-confused-with-bidirectional-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/deserializing-objects-with-bi-directional-many-to-many-relations

Comment: http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/json-troubleshooting-circular-dependency-errors/

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/81228-infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-jpa

Comment: @user3233996 You said you downloaded `jackson-core-2.3.1.jar`, you should also download `jackson-annotations-2.3.1` to use `@JsonIgnore*` annotations. The import should be something like `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore`, not `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the @MGorgon answer useful.

In my case I want to use hibernate along with jersey but retrieve only id of relation (and not loading the entire object) in a RestFull json web service.

I end up creating a field for the id:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"parent"}) // this ignores the object for json serialization
public class Object{
  private int id;
  private AnotherObj parent;
  @Transient // this ignores the properties for hibernate mapping, cause we want to use the parent.getId() instead. You may have to put it in your get too
  private ind parent_id;
}
```

Then in your ObjectDao query you can define the parent id as parent_id if you need to get it from a relation :

something like "from files WHERE user_id = parent_id").

You will have to do this for all your queries:

```
  Object.setParent_id(Object.getParent().getId());
```

Because `parent_id` is transient, invisible to hibernate and it wont be listed otherwise.

And of course you should use LAZY relations (otherwise it would load the obj anyway). It works because the parent_id is a column of the object table, it wont need to make a call to parent.

This is useful when you have a lot of relations but you just need to query the id.